# XPath 1.0 select distinct attribute of siblings

Tags: xslt, xpath-1.0

I have hunted around, but haven't been able to get any of the ideas I've found to work.

These are a couple of nodes I have in an xml file (that is generated from a db)

```
<PANELS>        
<PANEL ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
<PANEL ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
<PANEL ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
</PANELS>
<ZONES>
<ZONE ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
<ZONE ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
<ZONE ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
</ZONES>
```

I want to be able to select the distinct ATTR3 from each of these.

Currently, this works for the first one
`//PANELS/PANEL[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding::*/@ATTR3))]`
and returns the expected result for '31'

But when I try to do the same for the second one, it returns nothing (I want it to return '31' again)
`//ZONES/ZONE[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding::*/@ATTR3))]`

I understand that the second one is not working because the value of ATTR3 is the same for all of them, but how do I get the distinct attribute value per node?

(This is being used as the predicate for a for-each that I am using to display each distinct value)

This is being used like this, one of these `for-each` for **ZONES** and one for **PANELS**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//PANELS/PANEL[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding::*/@ATTR3))]">
<xsl:sort select="@ATTR3"/>
<xsl:value-of select="@ATTR3" />
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I would like it to return

```
PANELS: 31

ZONES: 31
```

I have tried using `preceding-sibling` instead of `preceding`, but then I get

```
PANELS: 31, 31

ZONES: 31
```

Each one is in a template like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="//HEADER/ZONES" >              
    <fo:block font-size="10pt">
        <fo:table  table-layout="fixed" > 
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(1)"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="proportional-column-width(7)"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell  border-bottom="none">
                        <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                            <xsl:text>Zones:</xsl:text>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell >                       
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//HEADER/ZONES/ZONE[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3))]">
                                <xsl:sort select="@ATTR3"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@ATTR3" />
                                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>             
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do you mean `preceding-sibling` instead of `preceding`?

Comment: I tried preceding-sibling, but in this example, that ends up returning 31 twice

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted? Once *31* from the first `<PANEL>` element, and once again *31* from the first `<ZONE>` element. Which is what I get from `//PANELS/PANEL[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3))] | //ZONES/ZONE[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3))]`.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve them separately.  So I need 31 once for PANELS, and 31 once for ZONES.  When I try with preceding-sibling in my XSLT stylesheet (it displays the PANELS first and then the ZONES) I get PANELS: 31, 31 and ZONES: 31

Comment: I'm getting `PANELS: 31 ZONES: 31` if I insert your above XSLT fragment, and an equivalent fragment for `<Zones>`, into a template that matches `/`, using `preceding-siblings` in both `<xsl:for-each>` loops.

Comment: Would it matter then, that this is inside a template like this? <xsl:template match="//HEADER/ZONES" > and an equivalent one for PANELS?  I have tried it like you suggested and am still getting PANELS: 31, 31

Comment: Works for me, too. Output: `ZONES: 31 ZONES: 31`

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work all morning.  I took out the excess //HEADER/ZONES/ part, and tried preceding-sibling again and this time it worked.  Thank you for your help! Is there some way I can mark your comment as having answered my question? I am sorry you found my question to be lacking research--I have been hunting all over and trying things with no success so finally decided to post my question.

Comment: froglander: Not only is this code of the accepted answer unnecessary verbose and complicated, and has fragments that are never executed (like the comma, that is never output, but it also doesn't produce the result wanted by you (the string "Panels" isn't present in the generated output).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XSLT uses `preceding-siblings` instead of `preceding` and thus produces the correct number of repetitions of the *31*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="//HEADER/ZONES">
        ZONES:
        <xsl:for-each select="//ZONES/ZONE[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3))]">
            <xsl:sort select="@ATTR3"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ATTR3" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//HEADER/PANELS">
        PANELS:
        <xsl:for-each select="//PANELS/PANEL[not(@ATTR3 = (preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3))]">
            <xsl:sort select="@ATTR3"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@ATTR3" />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output for this document:

```
<HEADER>
    <PANELS>
        <PANEL ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
        <PANEL ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
        <PANEL ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
    </PANELS>
    <ZONES>
        <ZONE ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
        <ZONE ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
        <ZONE ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
    </ZONES>
</HEADER>
```

is as follows:

```
    ZONES:
    31
    PANELS:
    31
```

Comment: Not only is this code unnecessary verbose and complicated, and has fragments that are never executed (like the comma, that is never output, but it also doesn't produce the result wanted by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**This short (13 lines) and simple transformation -- just one template, no hardcoded strings**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="t/*[*/@ATTR3]">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(), ':')"/>
     <xsl:for-each select="*/@ATTR3[not(. = ../preceding-sibling::*/@ATTR3)]">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', .)"/>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML (wrapped into a single top element to become a well-formed) document**:

```
<t>
    <PANELS>
        <PANEL ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
        <PANEL ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
        <PANEL ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31"/>
    </PANELS>
    <ZONES>
        <ZONE ATTR1="7"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
        <ZONE ATTR1="8"  ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
        <ZONE ATTR1="8A" ATTR2="37" ATTR3="31" />
    </ZONES>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
PANELS: 31 ZONES: 31
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's XSLT, I believe the idea is to generate comma separated values in the output for each of the distinct values. The example document just happened not to include multiple distinct values.

Comment: @MadsHansen, This solution produces exactly what the OP has shown in his question as the wanted answer. I don't want to guess (with great probability of error) what he might have wanted, but not shown in his question. As for the different distinct values, this solution produces correct results in case there are more than one distinct attribute values. It just uses a space as the separator -- not a comma.