# take attribute node and print distinct value using xslt

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

```
<page>
  <tab dim="70"></tab>
  <tab dim="40"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="70"></tab>
</page>
```

how to get the value of tab's dim attributes and take out the distinct value using xslt.means it will print 30,40,70

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the distinct attribute values, you can use this XPath:

```
/page/tab[not(@dim=preceding-sibling::tab/@dim)]/@dim
```

A possible XSLT template would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/page/tab[not(@dim=preceding-sibling::tab/@dim)]/@dim">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(., substring(',', 2 - (position() != last())))"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To [transform the source document with the stylesheet in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php), you can use:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('collection.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('collection.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

This will give 30,40,70 in the output.

You can achieve the same without an XSLT by simply doing:

```
$page = simplexml_load_file('NewFile.xml');
$dims = $page->xpath('/page/tab[not(@dim=preceding-sibling::tab/@dim)]/@dim');
$dims = array_map('strval', $dims);
sort($dims);
echo implode(',', $dims);
```

Also see

- http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html
- [How do I generate a comma-separated list with XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666584/how-do-i-generate-a-comma-separated-list-with-xslt-xpath)
- [XPath 1.0 select distinct attribute of siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363678/xpath-1-0-select-distinct-attribute-of-siblings)

Comment: can you refer to any resource on that. so that i can look further?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping using `preceding-sibling::someName` is notoriously slow (O(N^2) -- quadratical) and can be prohibitive to use on large node-sets.

**Here is a simple and most efficient [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kTabByDim" match="tab" use="@dim"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "tab[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kTabByDim',@dim)[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="@dim" data-type="number"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="tab">
   <xsl:if test="position() >1">,</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="@dim"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<page>
  <tab dim="70"></tab>
  <tab dim="40"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="30"></tab>
  <tab dim="70"></tab>
</page>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
30,40,70
```